# while scroll the screen app bar layout hide data from the bottom side of app bar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have an android app with activity...

and i want layout like [this image](http://bmptechnologies.com/my.gif)

I used collapsing toolbar layout using reference [link](https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea)

but i did not get output as i want.

What i tried is following..

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/materialup.appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/agent_detail_collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:titleEnabled="false">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:elevation="5dp">


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:id="@+id/agent_detail_pic"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                            android:src="@drawable/holder_image"/>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.5"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingRight="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/agent_detail_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left"
                                android:text="Agent Name"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="18dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"/>




                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/agent_detail_type"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Buying Agent, Selling Agent"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="14dp"/>





                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/agent_detail_address"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Philadelphia, NewYork"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textSize="14dp"/>


                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/agent_detail_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>




                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_rect"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp">


                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/agent_detail_tabs"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_rect"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/agent_detail_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

suggest me what should I do to get this type of layout..

Thanks in advance.